# I am trying to use reindex in Pandas to make a column the index but is getting an error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

"I want to make column ID the index but I get a error.  What am I doing wrong? I will appreciate any help"

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# Creating the dataframe  
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 5, 3, 4, 2],
                   "B": [3, 2, 5, 3, 4],
                   "C": [2, 2, 7, 3, 4],
                   "D": [4, 3, 6, 12, 7],
                   "ID": [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]})
# Print the dataframe
print(df)
# Output
#    A  B  C   D  ID
# 0  1  3  2   4   1
# 1  5  2  2   3   2
# 2  3  5  7   6   3
# 3  4  3  3  12   4
# 4  2  4  4   7   5
#
# reindexing = make column ID the new index values
df.reindex("ID")
```

Comment: Use `df.set_index('ID')`

Comment: Thanks jezrael. When will you then use reindex?

Comment: If need add new values to `index`